# Gmaps4rails : Get the location object id when click on the associated marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I am using [Gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) in a Rails 3 application.
I found a way to trigger a javascript function when I click on a marker on the map but I didn't found how to get the object id associated to the marker

Here is my code :

```js
var markers_to_monitor = Gmaps.map.markers;
 for (var i = 0; i < markers_to_monitor.length; ++i) {
 google.maps.event.addListener(markers_to_monitor[i].serviceObject, 'click',loadloc(i));
}
```

I need to call loadloc with the object id as set in the db and not the marker index i. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the third option in addListener to a function tied to the event. Like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(event, index) {
    return function(){
        loadloc(index);
      }
    })(marker,i));
```

Adapted from: http://srsz750b.appspot.com/api3/polylines-multiple.html